# How to track back where a script is scheduled in crontab

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I have scheduled one shell script in cron that fires emails depending on the condition.
I have modified the sender email address.
Now , the issue is while i tested the script in different test environments, somewhere probably it is still active and firing emails from test environment. I have checked crontabs in test environments but nowhere i found out it is scheduled.

Can you guys help me on how to track back where from those emails getting triggered? which instance? which cron etc.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest consulting the cron log file. This file records when and what programs cron starts on behalf of which user.

For FreeBSD this is `/var/log/cron`. On Linux, as always, it may depend on your distro, the cron implementation, phase of the moon :-) Running `man cron` might point you at the right file in the `FILES` section.